# im new to kivy and ids and object property confuses me

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So I am new to this kivy or programming really, i looked at a tutorial online like most do and i copied the video's code and it works, so i wanted to start from scratch and everything was going fine until i ran into this problem, its about object property and the .kv
For some reason I get an error  NameError: name 'shape' is not defined, this was after I did the tutorial and wanted to start from scratch

```
<MyFirstWidget>:
    shape: shape
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Ellipse:
            id: "shape"
            pos: 0,0
```

here is the python file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyFirstWidget(Scatter):
    shape = ObjectProperty(None)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyFirstWidget()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

i just want it to work, I cant really progress without making sure that it knows Im referencing to the Ellipse

Comment: I believe that you can only assign ids to widgets. A canvas instruction is not a widget.

Answer (score 1):

id in kv language is not a string.  You have quotes around your id value, "shape" should be shape without quotes.

From the kv language webpage at https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#

> Warning When assigning a value to id, remember that the value isn’t a
> string. There are no quotes: good -> id: value, bad -> id: 'value' An
> id is a weakref to the widget and not the widget itself. As a
> consequence, storing the id is not sufficient to keep the widget from
> being garbage collected.